# Using SAS EG to get percentages - again

Tags: sas

Hopefully this is a relatively easy question for someone to be able to help me with. I am a newbie to SAS (and programming).

I have a dataset that has numerous variables each measuring time spent at different activities, with approx. 18,000 unique entries.

I need to get the percentage that each of these variables contribute to the total amount of time spent. I know how to do this just not how to make SAS do it.

Here is a screenshot of some of the variables along with the total at the far right. Please let me know if you need anything else.

[image: Here is a screenshot of some of the variables]

DomPazz and momo1644 both contributed useful solutions which are contributing to my understanding of SAS. However both solutions covered doing this on a row by row basis suggesting I was unclear about what I am actually trying to achieve. I am trying to get a total for each of the variables and then find the percentage that that total contributes to the overall total. If I was doing this 'by hand' it would be v1_total/overall-total * 100/1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the row total, calculate all column totals then drive the percentage. The previous answers were calculating the Row totals only.

SAS Code:

```
data have;
input surfm wskim Outdoorm dancem fishm snkrm tenpm Leisurem totadmin;
datalines;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 180
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 180
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 98.75
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 30
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 30
0 0 0 0 120 0 0 120 750
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 30
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1291.25
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 370
0 0 0 15 0 0 0 15 160
;
RUN;
/*Calculate Total time per Row*/
data row_totals;
set have;
total= surfm + wskim + Outdoorm + dancem + fishm + snkrm + tenpm + Leisurem + totadmin;
run;
/*Calcualte Percentages*/
proc sql;
create table want as
select
sum(surfm)/sum(total) format=percent10.2 as surfm,
sum(wskim)/sum(total) format=percent10.2 as wskim,
sum(Outdoorm)/sum(total) format=percent10.2 as Outdoorm,
sum(dancem)/sum(total) format=percent10.2 as dancem,
sum(fishm)/sum(total) format=percent10.2 as fishm,
sum(snkrm)/sum(total) format=percent10.2 as snkrm,
sum(tenpm)/sum(total) format=percent10.2 as tenpm,
sum(Leisurem)/sum(total)   format=percent10.2 as Leisurem,
sum(totadmin)/sum(total) format=percent10.2 as totadmin,
sum(total) as total
from row_totals
;
quit;
```

Output:

[image: output]

```
surfm=0.00% wskim=0.00% Outdoorm=0.00% dancem=0.44% fishm=3.54% snkrm=0.00% tenpm=0.00% Leisurem=3.98% totadmin=92.04% total=3390
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you! I have one other query. Is there a quicker way to add the data lines, as I have just rechecked and there are over 25,000 of them!

Comment: You are welcome. instead of adding data lines; Just save your data to csv or excel file, drag and drop it in EG. EG will  do the import and creates a table for the file which you can use in the code  above.

Comment: Again thank you! Learning SAS independently is challenging when you have no programming experience so this resource is invaluable.

Comment: Always happy to help. EG is very powerful tool, you can do a lot of stuff with point and click  without coding experience.